# How can I use @Before tag from cucumber with @Parameters tag from TestNG for a same method

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

How can I use @Before tag from Cucumber and @Parameters tag from TestNG for a same method?

I tried with fetching the parameters from testng.xml file and feeding to @Before tag method, however some how @Before tag gets the value as null before the actual value is passed to this method. I wanted to use @Parameters tag on the same method where I use @Before tag, so that it will take the value and pass onto the next implementation methods to execute.

```
    @Parameters({"port"})
    public void setup(String port) {
        logger.info("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^TC running on " + System.getProperty("deviceType")
                + "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
        int portInt = Integer.parseInt(port);
        if (!(Base.checkIfServerIsRunning(4723))) {

            System.out.println("Attempting to start Appium server automatically");

            service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder().usingPort(portInt)
                    // .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node.exe"))
                    .withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js")));
            service.start();

            appiumServiceUrl = service.getUrl().toString();
            System.out.println("Appium Service Address : - " + appiumServiceUrl);

            base = new Base();
            base.capabilities(port);
            System.out.println(driver.getDeviceTime());

        } else {
            System.out.println("Server already running on this port: ");
        }
    }
```

Expected: I want the parameter to read by the method
Actual: Error message -

```
Message: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: When a hook declares an argument it must be of type cucumber.api.Scenario. public void stepdefinitions.Hooks.setup(java.lang.String)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:52)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at runner.Runner.feature(Runner.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
```

Comment: The cucumber hooks can either accept a Scenario as a parameter or no parameter at all. Maybe you can move the port number in a system property similar to what u have for device type.

Comment: okay, thanks.@Grasshopper